# Chrome extension description in web store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

there is something that i can't figure out about the description of a chrome extension.
 it is mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#description) that the description in the manifest should only contain plain string with less than 32 characters but i want to have a longer description for my extension as anyone did on the Chrome Web Store. 
So i provided a longer description on the dashboard but i still can see the short one on the Web Store. It seems like the description on i set on the dashboard page is never used.

1) Can anyone tell me how to set a long description for my extension ?

The second problem is that i wan to internationalize that description and so far i only use the i18n mechanism on the description set in the manifest file.

2) Supposing i am able to set a long description that is displayed on the Chrome Web Store, how can i make it available for different languages ?

Thanks

Comment: `i18n ` will help you to make it available for different languages

Comment: Both descriptions are used, the short one being in bold and the long one from dashboard is placed underneath. Did you make sure to publish your changes, or did you just save it as a draft?

Comment: I did publish the extension and it was available for my testers. Now it is available to the public but the long description is still missing.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, the long description is part of the Webstore listing.

Look at this guide for [applying i18n](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n) for your item.

Specifically, as long as your webstore item is i18n-enabled, the [detailed description can be edited](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#longDescription) for all supported languages from the "Edit item" page. You will see a selector at the top:

[image: Locale selection]

Answer (score 3):

The long description gets entered when publishing the extension, not in the manifest.